# Esperanto word for (gymnast’s) mat

Tags: single-word-requests, lexicon

I’m looking for a suitable translation for the object named “mat” in English and used in e.g. gymnastics or yoga: that is, either a piece of foam covered in vinyl/plastic/leather or a piece of PVC/rubber without filling.

Esperanto has the (fundamental) word *mato* but according to the definition in PIV, it has to be a woven piece, such as a door mat or the one placed on the floor in many Asian cultures:

> maldelikata kovraĵo aŭ tapiŝo el plektita pajlo, junko, basto, stipo ks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd simply use **mato**. Most of the meaning is there in the PIV definition. I wouldn't worry too much about the **woven** part. Most languages would probably have similarly defined a **mat** before other types were invented.

Of course if you want to specifically say a gymnastics mat:
**gimnastika mato, gimnastikmato**

Or a yoga mat:
**joga mato, jogmato**

Other possibilities are: **vato** (wadding, **vati** - to pad), or **pufo** (padding, puff)

Comment: **vato** is already reserved for the material _kombita k premita kotono_. maybe _vatmato_ then? almost unpronounceable! :-D 
thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

The right word to use is certainly *mato*. PIV is notorious for presenting definitions that contain details which do not hold for all the objects nameable by the defined word.